# Post values to Marketo form with PHP

Tags: marketo

I've a marketo form which I fill with the values I got through POST method and url-parameters, I want to submit these data and values to marketo form without the use of marketo form submit button, Is it possible? to submit values to marketo using specific buttons I create. Doing that server-side or client side, Doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. (Sending Marketo form values using CURL because the values were coming through an API from a native app.)

This article helped me to set this up https://community.marketo.com/MarketoResource?id=kA650000000GsXXCA0

You basically need to get your MunchkinID, formID and the submit URL. All described in the article. Then the rest is just a CURL POST submit.

I would suggest setting up a smart list based on form submissions so you can see what is coming into Marketo with each attempt.  There is a slight delay between submitting the data and it's visibility in the smart list but if you are patient you can tweak things a bit.

I also found that I needed to use the field names in the form (I pulled these from the DOM) rather than the API field names as suggested in the article.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to use the Munchkin API, which is client-side JavaScript: http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/websites/lead-tracking-munchkin-js/#associatelead